# Bluetooth discovering is not working

Tags: android, if-statement, broadcastreceiver

I am developing bluetooth application. In my app i have the following code. when the bluetooth is off means my else statement switch on the bluetooth on discover the list of devices (*it working fine)* otherwise if statement will run and get the list of devices.

```
My problem is "if condition is runnning but it doesn't discover the devices"
```

. anybody can suggest a solution.

```
if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {

        registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();
    } else {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(i1);

        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
                btAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }, 5000);

    }
```

//receiver detecting device code

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            items += device.getName() + ",";

        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

};
```